# Why aren't my pointer functions working

Tags: php, arrays

This is kind of a dumb  question, but I can't figure out why my pointer functions aren't working. Why aren't they working?

```
$r = array("boo", "goo", "buzz");

while($r = current($r))
{
 echo $r . '<br />';
 next($r);
}
```

Comment: You're assigning, not comparing.

Comment: You are using the same variable name for the array and the current value

Comment: You're reusing the variable `$r`. Overwriting the array with a value of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that assignment on the while:

Example:

```
$r = array("boo", "goo", "buzz");
while(current($r)) { // get current until true so it will loop, dont assign, you will overwrite r (the array), you could assign a new variable name instead, then use that new name to echo
    echo current($r) . '<br />'; // echo current pointer, not the whole array
    next($r); // shift to next pointer
}
```

or

```
$r = array("boo", "goo", "buzz");
while($a = current($r)) { // now you can assign, you won't overwrite `$r`
    echo $a . '<br />';
    next($r); // move to next pointer in r
}
```

Comment: ...and don't try to echo an array :)

Comment: Curious about the second example here. How does the loop know to end? if $a is being set to current($r) couldn't that happen forever? Or does next($r) go out of bounds or something, lol. I'm not sure what all is happening there...

Comment: @user2296112 no its just simple, when the pointer reach the end of the array, `current()` simply return false, which in turn dissatisfy the truthfullness of the loop (false), therefore ending the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
$r = array("boo", "goo", "buzz");

while(list($var, $val) = each($r))
{

 echo $val . '<br />';


}
```